# Importing Single New Sales Orders From Spreadsheet

Tags: orders, import, sales-order, sales, csv

Please can anyone help me with where to get an extension like this... (free or paid)

I am trying to find a solution for my ordering process for my customers.

My customers send me orders on an excel spreadsheet. I then process them myself. There are 300 rows with products. There are columns for various things. One of them is a unique sku/barcode.

What I want to do is, login to magento, click a customer, create an order, then without manually adding each item in just click upload and the quantity of all the sku's on the spreadsheet are automatically added to the cart.

I just want to be able to click a current customer in my base, then upload order. All the sku's are uploaded and then I carry on as normal.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any advice given.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of modules out there on Magento connect to do there for this sort of things.

Even free ones...

Take a look here and see if there is something you like:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=Bulk+Import%2BExport+Orders+to+CSV&pl=0